# How to extend the BOS descriptor in FunctionFS?

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi4, webusb, functionfs

I'm trying to implement a simple WebUSB device on a Raspberry Pi 4. I've created a Linux USB Gadget for this purpose with a FunctionFS function. Currently I've taken the [usb/ffs-test.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/tools/usb/ffs-test.c) example from the Linux kernel as a basis.

According to this excellent [Google blog by Reilly Grant](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb) on "Building a Device for WebUSB", I have to extend the Binary device Object Store (BOS) with the [Microsoft OS compatibility descriptors](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb) to get this to work on Windows. I could also add the WebUSB descriptors to it but this is not a functional requirement.

However I'm stuck on this step, how do I extend the BOS with FunctionFS? This is my first experience with FunctionFS or USB for that matter, so I could be missing something obvious. I've found some `usb_os_desc_header` struct defined [here in usb/functionfs.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/include/uapi/linux/usb/functionfs.h#L58), but I don't know if this is what I need or how I should use it.

Comment: Have you considered using ConfigFS instead? There's an excellent blog post with info on how to set the MS OS descriptors: http://irq5.io/2016/12/22/raspberry-pi-zero-as-multiple-usb-gadgets/

Comment: I already use ConfigFs to create my gadget, but I use FunctionFS to create my own function instead of the RNDIS function used in the blog post. Following the example in the blog doesn't immediately work for me. The `os_desc` folder doesn't contain a `interface` folder, which may be related. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out as well, so here's what I had to do (based on tools/usb/ffs-test.c).

A user space function must write all descriptors to ep0, so the trick is to extend your descriptors struct:

- add `__le32 os_count` after `ss_count`
- add `struct usb_os_desc_header os_header` and `struct usb_ext_compat_desc os_desc` after `ss_descs`
- `FUNCTIONFS_HAS_MS_OS_DESC` needs to be added to `header.flags`

Here's how I initialise the new fields for WinUSB compatibility, I presume WebUSB in general works similar:

```
    .os_count = cpu_to_le32(1),
    .os_header = {
        .interface = cpu_to_le32(1),
        .dwLength = cpu_to_le32(sizeof(descriptors.os_header) + sizeof(descriptors.os_desc)),
        .bcdVersion = cpu_to_le32(1),
        .wIndex = cpu_to_le32(4),
        .bCount = cpu_to_le32(1),
        .Reserved = cpu_to_le32(0),
    },
    .os_desc = {
        .bFirstInterfaceNumber = 0,
        .Reserved1 = cpu_to_le32(1),
        .CompatibleID = {'W', 'I', 'N', 'U', 'S', 'B', 0, 0},
        .SubCompatibleID = {0},
        .Reserved2 = {0},
    }
```